# Where can I find the Minimum Connections Times for a given airline/airport?

Tags: air-travel, online-resources, short-connections

Questions about [Minimum Connections Times](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/53533/minimum-connection-times-at-yul-allowing-for-us-pre-clearance) often list a table with the MCTs for a given airline/airport. Is there a general database of such information for major airports/airlines worldwide?

Comment: Just to be clear for some people reading the question wondering why the information is not usually published on the airport websites: MCT information is often specific to a pair of terminals and a pair of carriers. But it can be varied at certain times of the year (maybe Fridays are busy so the MCT is different on Fridays) or even for connecting from one exact flight to another exact flight (we want AA 1234 to be able to connect to AA 5678, so we lower the MCT for that pair). The full MCT information for JFK contains 2306 exceptions to the "normal" rule.

Comment: @Calchas And the list published on AC's site in the linked post is somewhat simplified too... EF shows exceptions depending on aircraft type

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Minimum Connection Times are not freely published anywhere to my knowlege. A subscription to a site such as [expertflyer](http://www.expertflyer.com/) is required. That site accesses MCT via a GDS interface.

The only way I can think of emulating this, is to perform queries on [ITA Matrix](http://matrix.itasoftware.com/) specifying a maximum connection time with the /maxconnect flag and then performing some sort of targetted search. Note however, that MCTs vary by combination of inbound and outbound airline, flight numbers, and other criteria.

If you'd like to purchase a subcription to access MCT data, you can do so on [OAG's site](http://www.oag.com/schedules/mcts).

> Minimum connection times (MCT) is the single most comprehensive source
>   of MCT data available in the market. Updated daily and containing
>   100,000 industry-standard individual MCTs and airline-specific
>   exceptions.

Answer (score 2):

Minimum Connection Time (MCT) is not determined for an Airport or even an Airline.  And really, MCT is not a thing, it's an internal figure used to validate itineraries.**

So, there is no "List of Minimum Connection Times" for an *airport or airline* because that's not how it works.  (Edited to avoid confusion with the OAG list which is based on flights as described below.)

MCT is determined by the airline for a flight pair based on a combination of several factors including terminal configuration, origin of the incoming flight (domestic or int'l) and historical data.

For instance, American Airlines could have >5 MCT's they use at LAX:

1. Eagle <-> Eagle could be 35 minutes since Eagle gates are max 250ft apart.
2. Mainline <-> Eagle
3. Mainline <-> Mainline
4. International -> Mainline
5. International -> Eagle

If the connection is offered on their web site, it meets their MCT for those conditions.

**If you try this out for yourself, pick two flights where the scheduled arrival is ~30 before scheduled departure.  Then call Reservations and tell them you want to book those specific flights.  The agent will build the itinerary but will not be able to sell it because it doesn't meet even a domestic MCT.

To answer the specific question, call the airline or search their web site, they may have this there but only as a guideline.